# How to solve issue "cannot resolve method collect in optional double"?

Tags: stream, set

I've created tests and now I am struggling with implementation using Stream. Please advise how  Stream in methods getOrdersCount() and  getOrdersTotalValue() should look like? Right now I get  ".collect" in red in both methods with error notes "cannot resolve method collect in optional double". Why and how to fix this?

```
class ShopTestSuite {


    Shop shop = new Shop();

    Order order1 = new Order(12.30, LocalDate.of(2020, 12, 12), "marta123");
    Order order2 = new Order(67.89, LocalDate.of(2019, 1, 12), "Tomek_K");
    Order order3 = new Order(123.90, LocalDate.of(2020, 2, 2), "Sylwia");
    Order order4 = new Order(22.90, LocalDate.of(2020, 6, 20), "Sylwia");

 @Test
    public void shouldReturnOrdersCount() {
        // When
        Integer result = shop.getOrdersCount();
        // Then
        assertEquals(4, result);
    }

 @Test
    public void shouldOrdersTotalValue() {
        // When
        Double result = shop.getOrdersTotalValue();
        // Then
        assertEquals(146.8, result);
    }


@BeforeEach
    public void initializeShop () {
            shop.addOrder(order1);
            shop.addOrder(order2);
            shop.addOrder(order3);
            shop.addOrder(order4);

        }
```

Shop class:

```
public class Shop {

private Set<Order> orders = new HashSet<>();

 public double getOrdersTotalValue(){
        return this.orders
                .stream()
                .mapToDouble(Order ::getValue).sum()
                .collect(Collectors.toSet())  //"cannot resolve method collect in optional double"
    }

public int getOrdersCount(){
        return this.orders
                .stream()
                .count()
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());  //"cannot resolve method collect in optional double"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you don't nead collect(Collectors.toSet()):

```
 public double getOrdersTotalValue(){
    return this.orders
            .stream()
            .mapToDouble(Order ::getValue).sum();
}

public int getOrdersCount(){
    return (int)this.orders
            .stream()
            .count();
}
```